# Python Twisted Client Connection Lost

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web, twisted.client, twisted.internet

I have this twisted client, which connects with a twisted server having an index. I ran this client from command-line. It worked fine. Now I modified it to run in loop (see `main()`) so that I can keep querying. But the client runs only once. Next time it simply says `connection lost \n Connection lost - goodbye!`.

What am i doing wrong? In the loop I am reconnecting to the server, it that wrong?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import protocol

from settings import AS_SERVER_HOST, AS_SERVER_PORT

# a client protocol
class Spell_client(protocol.Protocol):
    """Once connected, send a message, then print the result."""

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write(self.factory.query)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        "As soon as any data is received, write it back."
        if data == '!':
            self.factory.results = ''
        else:
            self.factory.results = data
        self.transport.loseConnection()

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "\tconnection lost"

class Spell_Factory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = Spell_client

    def __init__(self, query):
        self.query   = query
        self.results = ''

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "\tConnection failed - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "\tConnection lost - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()

# this connects the protocol to a server runing on port 8090
def main(): 
    print 'Connecting to %s:%d' % (AS_SERVER_HOST, AS_SERVER_PORT)
    while True:
        print
        query = raw_input("Query:")
        if query == '': return
        f = Spell_Factory(query) 
        reactor.connectTCP(AS_SERVER_HOST, AS_SERVER_PORT, f)
        reactor.run()
        print f.results
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't quite understand how the Twisted reactor works.

`reactor.run()` is starting up the reactor's event-loop --- it's a blocking call that loops "forever".

See http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/core/howto/reactor-basics.html for various reactor-related topics.

Comment: so what does this mean? I should now use a `reactor` in a loop?

Comment: The reactor *is* the loop. See here for an example of how to deal with standard input: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/doc/core/examples/stdin.py