# Python Chat Client not Remaining Open

Tags: python, chat

I have recently started developing a server-client chat protocol for learning purposes (later I would like to do more with this communication, but for now this suffices. Needless to say, I am still early into the learning phase of this portion of Python, but I have modified some examples to a server and a client that I found online. The communication works well from what I've seen so far, but I have to relaunch the client every time I want to send a message to the server.
Here is the code:

server:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.protocols import basic


class Echo(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        "As soon as any data is received, write it back."
        self.transport.write(data)

class MyChat(basic.LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "Got new client!"
        self.factory.clients.append(self)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "Lost a client!"
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "received", repr(data)
        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.message(data)

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')

def main():
    """This runs the protocol on port 8000"""
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = MyChat
    factory.clients = []
    reactor.listenTCP(8000,factory)
    reactor.run()

# this only runs if the module was *not* imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

client:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol


# a client protocol

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    """Once connected, send a message, then print the result."""

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("hello, world!")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        "As soon as any data is received, write it back."
        print "Server said:", data
        self.transport.loseConnection()

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "connection lost"

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = EchoClient

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        connector.connect()
        print "Connection failed - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        connector.connect()
        print "Connection lost - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()


# this connects the protocol to a server runing on port 8000
def main():
    f = EchoFactory()
    client = EchoClient()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8000, f)
    reactor.run()

# this only runs if the module was *not* imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What am I forgetting to add so that I can have multiple clients connected to the server and stay connected?
I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530845/python-twisted-client-connection-lost) and [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/doc/core/examples/stdin.py) (the first one seems to be the same type of question) but I'm still confused as to how to fix this issue. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: FYI your links didn't come through properly.

Comment: oops! thanks ill fix that

Comment: Should loseConnection be a part of dataReceived?